# Elasticsearch recommended max_content_length

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing docs in batches and try to find out what to prefer - reducing batches to fit existing max_content_length or enlarge limit, and index as much documents as possible per request.
What is recommended strategy for setting max_content_length for Elasticsearch? Is that ok to have 1GB limit, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the famous saying goes: It depends... :-)

There's no right answer to your question because the maximum size that you can send depends on what your cluster can handle based on the software/hardware specs it is running on.

The empirical way of figuring this out is to test different sizes and see which one offers the best throughput, while still allowing the cluster to serve user requests during peak times.